# Calculate ArcGIS field from Excel sheet in ArcPy

Tags: arcpy, field-calculator, excel

I want to calculate a field in shapefile from a field in Excel sheet using an ArcPy script. How can I write the last line in the below script?

```py
import arcpy
import xlrd
arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True

inputExcel = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)
inputSHP = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(1)

workbook = xlrd.open_workbook(inputExcel)
worksheet = workbook.sheet_by_name('Sheet1')

cursor1 = arcpy.UpdateCursor(inputSHP)

for row1 in cursor1:
    arcpy.CalculateField_management(in_table, field, expression, {expression_type}, {code_block})
```

Comment: `CalculateField` operates over all rows and `arcpy.UpdateCursor` is deprecated. Start over again using the documentation for `arcpy.da.UpdateCursor`. If you're updating from the Excel sheet, you should first to extract the values by key field into a dictionary. If you just want to insert values you should use a DA InsertCursor.

Comment: Its worth noting that arcpy can open Excel worksheets as tables directly.  No xlrd required.  Although, I think it's read only.  But can export tables to Excel as well (write-only).

Comment: Can you add an example of the data in excel and the calculation you are trying to perform?

Comment: It is one field in the excel with yes and no values and another one with dates

Answer (score 1):

You can do this without coding (or with just 1 line of code) with the [Join Fields](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/tool-reference/data-management/join-field.htm) tool.

Else Vince's suggestion of turning the excel join & value field into a dictionary is good.

Yet another way is to convert the Excel table to a temporary table, then just use the regular AddJoin & CalculateField workflow.

```
import arcpy

inputExcel = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)
inputSHP = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(1)

arcpy.conversion.ExcelToTable(inputExcel, "in_memory\\temp_tab1", 'Sheet1')

# make a layer and add the join 
arcpy.management.MakeFeatureLayer(inputSHP, "temp_lyr")
arcpy.management.AddJoin("temp_lyr", "join_field1", "in_memory\\temp_tab1", "join_field2")

# transfer the values
arcpy.management.CalculateField("temp_lyr", "target_field", "!source_field!")
```